# Parse error on JSON (Expecting 'string', 'number', 'null'

Tags: json, parsing

I'm keep getting JSON Parse error on this object

> "DC008":"PD 가격 $2.90/yd 에서 시작#10#10티앤티 난단에 나염작업#10#10나염비 \4,000/YD
>   (Digital 전사)#1010% loss#10#10판매가 수정 $7.30/yd ->
>   $7.70/yd(2014.01.30)#10#10#10H132491와 같음"

but I cannot figure out which character is hiding in this object

Can anyone please help me

btw #10 in the string is converted from \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since it seems to be a property key/value pair, you first have to enclose it in `{}`.

As another answer points out, the problem is with your backslash. The backslash, although permitted as an escape character in regular JS strings, is  **not** permitted in JSON (except for predefined cases such as `\t` for tab).

The backslash likely originated somewhere as a "won" symbol. In the Windows/ASCII world, the backslash (0x5c) is often used for, and displayed as, a won symbol (or yen symbol in the case of Japan). However, in Unicode, the backslash and won symbol are entirely different. You need to figure out who is responsible for emitting this string and ideally have them pass you a correctly Unicode-encoded string instead.

By the way, I assume you are aware that the `#10` are not going to magically turn into newlines. The correct JSON representation of that would be `\n`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Backslash was my problem. I've done re-converting #10 with newlines Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the \4.  I removed that and was able to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Found out that in the value section '\' has to come with some of characters such as \r, \n. Thank you